# fread causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, fread

Trying to create a file of 1024 bytes of random data. When I run this, I get a segmentation fault error on the fread line. Anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PERMS 0666

int main() {

   char buf[1024];

   if (creat("test.txt", PERMS) < 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "couldn't create file\n");
       exit(0);
   }

   char randomData[1024];
   FILE* fp;
   fp = (void*) open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY, PERMS);
   fprintf(stderr, "here\n");
   fread(&randomData, 1024, 1, fp);
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The real question is, why did you cast the return value of `open` to a `void*` ? That should have a big flashing warning to you that what you were doing was incorrect.

Comment: @usr55410 - If you resort to casts it is usually a good idea to check what you are doing. The line `fp = (void *)...` would indicate that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried it both with and without the & to see if this was the problem. Looks like I left the wrong attempt in this post.

Comment: @usr55410 - there are no problems related to `&` characters in your program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`open` return a file descriptor, not a `FILE *` pointer.  Use `fopen`:

```
fp = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
```

Aside:  What's up with that `(void *)` cast?  It's hiding the bug from you.  Psychic debugging tells me that you inserted the cast to get rid of an "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" warning, but that's not the right fix in this case.  When you get strange warnings like that, you should check out the documentation before resorting to inserting crazy casts all willy-nilly.

Aside 2:  Your program doesn't write any data into your `test.txt` file.  In fact, you leak the file descriptor you created immediately anyway, so it currently *can't* write anything. Even if you did manage to write through the 1024 bytes you're trying to read from `/dev/urandom`, it's not going to be text data, so that file extension is a bit weird.

Aside 3:  Why are you using `creat()` in the first place?  Its [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/creat/) says quite clearly "This interface is made obsolete by `open(2)`".